# Given a data table with outlier data points, how to determine whether the data table include global outliers or local outliers?

Tags: machine-learning, outliers

As we know, outliers are categorized into (i) global outliers and (ii) local outliers. Local outliers are outliers comparing to their local neighborhoods, instead of the global data distribution. There are many algorithms for detecting global outliers or local outliers.

My question is:
given a data table with outlier data points, how to find an unsupervised metric/measurement to determine: whether the data table include global outliers or local outliers? In this way, I will know how to select proper outlier detection algorithm for this data table?

Comment: Can you provide a definition for "global outliers" vs "local outliers"?

Comment: @gung here is the definition of local outliers: Outliers comparing to their local neighborhoods, instead of the global data distribution